# Не работает терминал в Atom с node.js (Команда не найдена)

Tags: javascript, node.js, atom

Установил `node.js`, `Atom`, плагин `platformio-ide-terminal`, но не работает команда `node`. Может кто сталкивался?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в обычной консоле? `Atom`  ребутни

Comment: А в обычной работает. Даже ноут перезагружал.